# How to link a tomcat application with ubuntu 14.04 server os on an azure server to dot tk domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, virtual-machines, azure, tomcat7

how to link a tomcat application with ubuntu 14.04 server os on an azure server to dot tk domain?

few doubts about azure vm:

I can only find one DNS name e.g. abc.cloudapp.net, but dot tk DNS panel requires at least two DNS names to work. How to fix this issue?

Is there any other service(s) on azure i could use to create DNS name for my abc.cloudapp.net, so i can have two DNS name for my custom dot tk domain?

p.s i don't have enough rep to tag .tk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to setup the nameserver or NS record. That is why you are being prompted for 2 names. Instead of this do the following:

Choose CNAME if you are choosing the subdomain (like www.foo.tk) and set it to abc.cloudapp.net.

Choose A if you are choosing the naked domain (like foo.tk) and set it to the IP that abc.cloudapp.net points to.

Comment: The problem is I couldn't find create CNAME OR Alias panel in dot tk anymore. they have change the UI  and naming

Comment: I see it under Manage Freenom DNS. See http://imgur.com/Z7P7xD0

Comment: thank you for your help. and may i ask how long will this (usually) take to complete? I just added Alias or A to my dot tk domain's record.